# Installing pip and numpy on Unix server without root access

Tags: python, numpy, unix, pip

I know this question has been asked and answered a number of times but none of those solutions have worked for me. I have installed Python 2.7 into a local directory and added it to my path. When I try to install numpy i get the following error:

> ImportError: No module named setuptools

I cannot simply `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools` because i don't have root access.

I need to install numpy and ideally have pip working for future applications.

Comment: Not sure about pip on it's own, but I use Anaconda (Python distribution with Numpy/Scipy, etc.) on my Mac, Linux, and Windows machines. It doesn't require root to install if you use the command line installer and install to your home directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0) Try to install packages that are isolated to the current user, use the --user flag:

```
pip install --user SomeProject
```

1a) I agree with @Pi Marillion here, use an isolated conda environment if you don't have root access. This way you keep your path clean.

To install conda:

Since I don't know about your OS, go to https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

After installation, update your conda (just in case):

```
conda update conda
```

To list the installed packages, you can do

```
conda list
```

You should see python installed. you can start an interpreter by typing `python` in the terminal.

There's conda cheat sheet that I found incredibly helpful:

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/cheatsheet.html

b) Now try installing via pip and **I think you might need python 3.x for setuptools.**

https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#id13

2) If this does not work you can still try

https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-stand-alone-command-line-tools/

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

First try `easy_install --user setuptools pip`. If that doesn't work you need to install things manually.

Download `setuptools-*.zip` from https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/#files. Unzip the archive, `cd` into the new directory and run `python2.7 setup.py install`.

Then try `pip install`. If it still doesn't work reinstall `pip`: download [`get-pip.py`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py) and run `python get-pip.py --user`.